# Match variables to produce outcome variable

Tags: r

I am trying to get the count of codes in the list of claims with line level information. There are 3 variables

1. Claim number - Remains same
2. Process date - Changes every time claim is processed again
3. Code - Repeats every time claim is processed again

I am trying to count how many codes are built on a claim.

Please see attached image of sample with given and expected information:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Please read posting guidelines. An example data and working code of what you have tried will be useful

Comment: Please, don't post images of data. That doesn't help to reproduce the problem and test an answer. See [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think you might be wanting sth like this:

```
dat <- data.frame("Claim Number" = 123456789,
              Date = rep(c("1-Jan", "1-Feb"), each = c(5)),
              Code = sample(c("bla", "blub", "gna"), 10, replace = T))


match_frame <- data.frame(Code = unique(dat$Code), 
                          Code_number = paste0("Cd", 
                                               seq_along(unique(dat$Code))))

dat$Code_number <- match_frame$Code_number[match(dat$Code, 
                                                 match_frame$Code)]
```

First it identifies the unique/distinct entries of codes and creates a counted name for them. Then the name is merged into the original date. I'm not using merge because that would change the row order in your table!

There are definatly more efficient and lean ways of doing this, yet it might help you in understanding how to solve this problem.

Best 
Sören